# SSIS Data conversion Package Error

Tags: ssis, package, data-conversion

This is what happens every time I try to run the package:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears this error is coming from a data flow task where you are trying to apply a text or Excel file source and import to a database destination.  The initial errors, which are likely causing the later ones, are due to an inconsistency in the data types.  Some of the source fields are defined as a Unicode where a non-Unicode is expected.  The message shows this is taking place with columns VILLE, HABITATION, and PROFESSION.

This can be corrected by inserting between the source and destination data flow tasks a Data Conversion.  Here you can convert the data types creating new fields that can be applied in the destination task mapping.

Hope this helps.